# Multiple PouchDB to single CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I need to submit data from multiple mobile apps. in my mobile app I am planning to use pouchdb to store the document, later I want this document to sync to couchdb one-way only.
what will happen if I submit data from multiple devices ? will pouch db create same document ID and overwrite data in couchDB ?

Answer (score 0):

The document ID will not be the same, assuming you're letting PouchDB create them (the likelihood of PouchDB generating the same ID twice is extremely low)